# How to make subclass accept superclass as value?

Tags: java, tree, subclass

I have a superclass called Tree and a subclass called AVLTree that extends the class Tree.

A tree has children that are also Tree typed. An AVLTree has children that are AVLTree. I want to use the methods i wrote on the  Tree class, on this case the getLeft(returns the left son) and setLeft(set the left son).

The problem is the compiler can't convert a Tree to an AVLTree, even though they have the same variables, structure and constructors.

Any ideas on how should I solve this? Or should I just write all the methods that just an AVLTree has on the Tree class?

The code:

Tree.java:

```
public class Tree<T extends Tree<T>> {
  private T left = null;
  private T right = null;
  private Object data = null;

  public Tree () {
    //nothing
  }
  public Tree (Object data, T left, T right) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }
  public Tree (Object data) {
    this.data = data;
  }


  //Get Values
  public T getLeft() {
    return this.left;
  }
  public T getRight() {
    return this.right;
  }
  public Object getData() {
    return this.data;
  }
  //Set Values
  public void setLeft(T left) {
    this.left = left;
  }
  public void setRight(T right) {
    this.right = right;
  }
  public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public T treeFromText(String in) {
    if (in=="()") return null;
    int i=0;
    T result = null;
    //Find expression
    int d = in.indexOf('c')+1;
    if (d==0) return null;


    int begl, endl, begr, endr;

    begl = d+1;
    endl = ClosingParentesis(in,begl);
    endr = in.length()-2;
    begr = OpeningParentesis(in,endr);

    T left = null, right = null;

    if (begl-endl==0) {
      left = null;
    } else left = treeFromText(in.substring(begl,endl+1));
    if (begr-endr==0) {
      right = null;
    } else right = treeFromText(in.substring(begr,endr+1));

    result.setData(in.charAt(d));
    result.setLeft(left);
    result.setRight(right);
    return result;
  }


  public static int ClosingParentesis(String in, int openPos) {
    int closePos = openPos;
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter > 0 && closePos < in.length()-1) {
      closePos++;
      if (in.charAt(closePos)=='(') counter++;
      if (in.charAt(closePos)==')') counter--;
    }
    return closePos;
  }

  public static int OpeningParentesis(String in, int closePos) {
    int openPos = closePos;
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter > 0 && openPos > 0) {
      openPos--;
      if (in.charAt(openPos)=='(') counter--;
      if (in.charAt(openPos)==')') counter++;
    }
    return openPos;
  }
```

AVLTree.java:

```
public class AVLTree extends Tree<AVLTree> {
  /*
  //Values and Variables
  private AVLTree left = null;
  private AVLTree right = null;
  private Object data;


  //Inicialization
  public AVLTree (Object data, AVLTree left, AVLTree right) {
    super(data,left,right);
  }
  public AVLTree (Object data) {
    super(data);
  }


  */
  public int getfactor() {
    return getHeight(this.getLeft())-getHeight(this.getRight());
  }
}
```

Test.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  AVLTree tree = new AVLTree();

  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  String in = console.nextLine().toLowerCase();

  tree = (AVLTree) tree.treeFromText(in); //The error is here.
  System.out.println(tree.getHeight());
  System.out.println(tree.TreePreOrder());


}
```

The way I expect it to work is that if the String 'in' in the Test.java is "(c3()(c2()()))" the return must be an Tree with value 3 and a right son with value 2. This return must be of type Tree or anything that extends Tree.

Comment: Please show us code snippets so that we can be sure we understand what you are asking.

Comment: @StephenC Just added the code on the question.

Comment: consider Tree as an interface and inplement it on a base class (perhaps BaseTree) and on the AVLTree.  Then just accept Tree (the interface) as a type

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the power of generics: define a new circular generic T:

```
public class Tree<T extends Tree<T>>
{
    T left;
    T right;

    public T doSomething()
    {
        return left;
    }

    public static class AVLTree extends Tree<AVLTree>
    {
        public AVLTree foo()
        {
            return doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: here is how you can create different tree instances:

import java.util.Objects;

```
public class TreesFactory
{
    public static AVLTree createAVLTreeFrom(String in)
    {
        return treeFromText(in, AVLTree::new);
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface SimpleFactory<T extends Tree<T>>
    {
        T createNew();
    }

    public static <T extends Tree<T>> T treeFromText(String in, SimpleFactory<T> treeFactory)
    {
        if (Objects.equals(in, "()"))
            return null;

        T result = treeFactory.createNew();
        //Find expression
        int d = in.indexOf('c') + 1;
        if (d == 0)
            return null;

        int begl, endl, begr, endr;

        begl = d + 1;
        endl = ClosingParentesis(in, begl);
        endr = in.length() - 2;
        begr = OpeningParentesis(in, endr);

        T left, right;

        if (begl - endl == 0)
        {
            left = null;
        }
        else
            left = treeFromText(in.substring(begl, endl + 1), treeFactory);
        if (begr - endr == 0)
        {
            right = null;
        }
        else
            right = treeFromText(in.substring(begr, endr + 1), treeFactory);

        result.setData(in.charAt(d));
        result.setLeft(left);
        result.setRight(right);
        return result;
    }


    public static int ClosingParentesis(String in, int openPos)
    {
        int closePos = openPos;
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter > 0 && closePos < in.length() - 1)
        {
            closePos++;
            if (in.charAt(closePos) == '(')
                counter++;
            if (in.charAt(closePos) == ')')
                counter--;
        }
        return closePos;
    }

    public static int OpeningParentesis(String in, int closePos)
    {
        int openPos = closePos;
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter > 0 && openPos > 0)
        {
            openPos--;
            if (in.charAt(openPos) == '(')
                counter--;
            if (in.charAt(openPos) == ')')
                counter++;
        }
        return openPos;
    }
}
```

And the Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = console.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    AVLTree tree = TreesFactory.createAVLTreeFrom(in);
    //...
}
```

Comment: okay, i did it like that and used a method that would get a string and parse it into a tree. The method should return what type of variable? if I return Tree it doesn't work.

Comment: Post the code so that I could understand you better

Comment: You can either do as Erick mentioned or you can extract treeFromText to a different factory class, and add another parameter to it - Factory<T> which is an interface with one method - create that returnes new T. Than you create a Factory for Tree, AVLTree, etc... pay attention that you initialize tree to null in treeFromText and never change it so null is always returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to get an `AVLTree` instantiated from a `String`, using the logic in `Tree.treeFromText`.

1. Declare `Tree` as `abstract`.
2. Create a new method in `Tree`:

   `abstract protected T createEmptyTree();`
3. Override that method in `AVLTree` to return an empty instance of `AVLTree`.

   `@Override
   protected AVLTree createEmptyTree() {
     return new AVLTree();
   }`
4. In `treeFromText()`, wherever you need to create an empty instance of `T`, invoke `createEmptyTree()`.

You already have the rest of the logic.

Try to avoid returning `null` anywhere. It's best to return an empty `AVLTree` instead of a `null`.